# Problem with a path between pgf 2.1 and pgf 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
      \path[fill=blue]  (0,0) -- plot function{x+1} -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
      \path[fill=blue]  plot function{x+1} -- (2,0)-- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With pgf 2.1 the two pictures are identical but with pgf 3.0 I get

[image]

Comment: No problem with an internal plot (`plot(\x,{\x+1})`)...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes  but it's not an explanation of my problem !

Comment: IMHO, it is a bug in TikZ 3.0 with external gnuplot function plot.

Comment: I created [a ticket for this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/318/). So, I vote to close this question...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in PGF/TikZ v3.0.0.